# BeautifulSoup: get contents[] as a single string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Anyone know an elegant way to get the entire contents of a soup object as a single string?

At the moment I'm getting `contents`, which is of course a list, and then iterating over it:

```
notices = soup.find("div", {"class" : "middlecontent"})
con = ""
for content in notices.contents:
    con += str(content)
print con
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also just use `soup.find('div', 'middlecontent')` - the second argument is class by default.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What about `contents = str(notices)` ?

Or maybe `contents = notices.renderContents()`, which will hide the div tag.

Comment: in new Beautiful Soup 4, renderContents() is now encode_contents()

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [join()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
notices = soup.find("div", {"class": "middlecontent"})
contents = "".join([str(item) for item in notices.contents])
```

Or, using a generator expression:

```
contents = "".join(str(item) for item in notices.contents)
```

Comment: In modern versions of Python, the square brackets are unnecessary and even deprecated - leaving them out creates a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension, which makes for somewhat better usage of memory and does not leak the name 'item' into the local variable scope.

Comment: @Karl, you're right, I guess I'm too fond of list comprehensions. Answer updated.

Comment: The way out of that is to train yourself to think that `[<comprehension stuff>]` is just syntactic sugar for `list(<comprehension stuff>)` that leaks the iteration variable as a side effect. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
__author__ = 'spouk'

import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def parse_contents_href(url, url_args=None, check_content_find=None, tag='a'):
    """
    parse href contents url and find some text in href contents [ for example ]
    """
    html = requests.get(url, params=url_args)
    page = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html.text)
    alllinks = page.findAll(tag,  href=True)
    result = check_content_find and filter(
        lambda x: check_content_find in x['href'], alllinks) or alllinks
    return result and "".join(map(str, result)) or False


url = 'https://vk.com/postnauka'
print parse_contents_href(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

But the list is recursive, so...
I think this will work.
I'm new to python, so the code may look a little weird

```
getString = lambda x: \
    x if type(x).__name__ == 'NavigableString' \
    else "".join( \
    getString(t) for t in x)

contents = getString(notices)
```